# geocode function removes special chracters

Tags: r, fonts, ggmap, geocode

Hi I am using the geocode function to get lat and lng data for some cities, but for some special alphabet character cities such as: "Marcos Juárez Argentina" or "Perú Argentina" it creates mistakes in generating the inquiry:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Per%FA%20Argentina&key=[**my api key**]
```

is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `enc2utf8()` function to read or set the declared encodings for a character vector:

```
> geocode(enc2utf8("Marcos Juárez Argentina"), output = 'more')
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Marcos%20Ju%C3%A1rez%20Argentina&sensor=false
       lon       lat     type     loctype                           address     north     south      east     west      locality
1 -62.1058 -32.69786 locality approximate marcos juárez, cordoba, argentina -32.67304 -32.71417 -62.07497 -62.1302 Marcos Juárez
  administrative_area_level_2 administrative_area_level_1   country
1    Marcos Juárez Department                     Cordoba Argentina
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a geocoding service that does not transliterate inputs: [example](https://geocode.xyz/Marcos%20Ju%C3%A1rez%20Argentina)

In Json:
https://geocode.xyz/Marcos%20Ju%C3%A1rez%20Argentina?json=1

{   "standard" : {      "addresst" : {},      "city" : "Marcos Juárez",      "prov" : "AR",      "countryname" : "Argentina",      "postal" : {},      "confidence" : "0.9"   },   "longt" : "-62.10158",   "alt" : {},   "elevation" : {},   "latt" : "-32.69679"}